# inverting an index using clusters

Tags: r

This code is about inverting an index using clusters.
Unfortunately I do not understand the line with recognize<-...
I know that the function Vectorize applies the inner function element-wise, but I do not understand the inner function here.
The parameters (uniq, test) are not defined, how can we apply which then? Also why is there a "uniq" as text right after?

```
slots <- as.integer(Sys.getenv("NSLOTS"))
cl <- makeCluster(slots, type = "PSOCK")

inverted_index4<-function(x){
    y <- unique(x) 
recognize <- Vectorize(function(uniq,text) which(text %in% uniq),"uniq",SIMPLIFY = F) 
y2 <- parLapply(cl, y, recognize, x)
unlist(y2,recursive=FALSE)   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The

> Vectorise()

function is just making a new element wise, vectorised function of the custom function

`function(uniq,text) which(text %in% uniq)`.

The `'uniq'` string is the argument of that function that you must specify you want to iterate over.  Such that now you can pass a vector of length greater than one for `uniq`, and get returned a list with an element for the output of the function evaluated for every element of the input vector `uniq`.

I *would* suggest the author make the code a little clearer, better commented etc. the vectorise function doesn't need to be inside the function call necessarily.
Note

> ParLapply()

isn't a function I recognise. But the `x` will be passed to the recognise function and the second argument text should presumably be defined earlier on, in the global environment, `.GlobalEnv()`.

Comment: you wrote: "Such that now you can pass a vector of length greater than one for uniq, and get returned a list with an element for the output of the function evaluated for every element of the input vector uniq." I do not understand this sentence. I guess the vector you can pass to uniq is in this case text, it is in the globenv. as you said, it is a vector with 100 words, 10 unique words in a random order. The output of the function is every word and the positions of it in the text vector. So what does which(text %in% uniq), "uniq" does? I can use any other word e.g. hello and it still works

Comment: Sorry - rereading this it was a bit confusing.  Some functions only take a length one argument e.g. function(uniq='some text'). This is the case for your function because you cant pass a vector to uniq in text %in% uniq (its not forbidden but it isn't useful) So we vectorise the function, Vfunction(uniq=c('some text','some more text').  uniq is now larger than length one, and the function will evaluate on each element individually like it is in a for loop - function('text'), and thenfunction('some more text) and output these results separately in a list.  Vectorise is just like a for loop.